# SQL Stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I have 3 tables:

- `tbl_Image` from which a list of all images will be obtained
- A `user` table from which User ID will be obtained
- and an association table of Image and Member called `tbl_MemberAssociation`.

My work flow is that a user can upload image and this will be stored in to image table. Then all users can view this image and select one of three choice provided along with the image. If user selects an option it will be added to Association table. No user can watch same image more than once. So multiple entries will not be there.

Now I want to find the % of match by getting the list of members choose the same option and different option corresponding to all common images for which they have provided their option.

I.e. say if 3 users say A, B and C view an image of tajmahal. If A and B opted beautiful as choice and C as "Not Good ". For another image say Indian Flag A B and C opted same as Salute. Then for User A: B have 100 % match (since they selected same option both times). For A : C have 50% match one among 2 same.

So this is my scenario, in which I have to find all matched corresponding to currently logged in User.

Please help me.... I am totally disturbed with this procedure.

Comment: Which **database system** and which version are you using?? Stored procedure code is typically not standardized between vendors...

Comment: Do I understand correctly: you want a stored procedure that takes two user ID's as input, and returns a percentage of how many answers are the same for these two users?? What if one user has given an answer and the other has not? Does this count - as a "different answer"? Or is that question skipped (since not both users have answered it)

Comment: i want to use SQL Server 2008

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made some assumptions about the actual structure of your tables, but if I understand what you are looking for then I think this query will get the results you are wanting.  You may have to make a few modifications to match your table structures.

```
    SELECT
        matches.UserName,
        CAST(matches.SameRatings AS FLOAT) / CAST(ratings.UserRatingCount AS FLOAT) AS MatchPercent
    FROM 
        tbl_User
    CROSS APPLY
    (
        SELECT
            COUNT(*) UserRatingCount
        FROM 
            tbl_MemberAssociation
        WHERE 
            UserId = tbl_User.UserId
    ) ratings
    CROSS APPLY
    (
        SELECT
            u1.UserId,
            u1.UserName,
            COUNT(*) AS SameRatings
        FROM 
            tbl_MemberAssociation ma
        INNER JOIN 
            tbl_MemberAssociation ma1 
        ON
            ma.ImageId = ma1.ImageId 
        AND ma.Rating = ma1.Rating 
        AND ma.UserId <> ma1.UserId
        INNER JOIN 
            tbl_User u1 
        ON 
            ma1.userId = u1.UserId
        WHERE 
            ma.UserId = tbl_User.UserId
        GROUP BY
            u1.UserId,
            u1.UserName
    ) matches
    WHERE
        tbl_User.UserId = @UserId
    ORDER BY
        MatchPercent DESC
```

@UserId could be passed as an input to the stored procedure.

The 1st CROSS APPLY "ratings" is getting a count of for the total number of ratings for the logged in user.

The 2nd CROSS APPLY "matches" is getting a count of the number of like ratings for the other users in the database.

The result set uses the counts calculated by the two CROSS APPLY queries to compute the match percentage between the logged in user and the other users who have rated the same images as the logged in user.